# PingReply's "RoundTripTime" is 0 very often? Why is this happening

Tags: c#, ping

I have a very odd issue that is happening when pinging a large amount of proxies. The "RoundTripTime" is returning 0 randomly.

If I run the proxy list through the checker a second time it will have different proxies returning up 0 and others returning with actual ms.

I thought this was maybe due to it being too many requests at once so I tried adding some manual sleep into it but that caused more "0" response times.

I'm seriously stuck and appreciate all help.

```
public static List<string> proxyList = new List<string>();
public static List<string> proxyNoPort = new List<string>();
public static int proxyCount;
public static int proxyTimeOut;
public static long pingResponseTime;

public static bool proxyTest()
{
    try
    {
        Ping pingTest = new Ping();
        PingReply pingResponse = pingTest.Send(proxyNoPort[proxyCount], proxyTimeOut);

        if (pingResponse != null && pingResponse.RoundtripTime < proxyTimeOut)
        {
            pingResponseTime = pingResponse.RoundtripTime;
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        proxyList.Remove(proxyList[proxyCount]);
        proxyNoPort.Remove(proxyNoPort[proxyCount]);
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Picture of program][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Nar.png

Notes from my own further testing:
If the number returns "0" making it re-ping the same proxy works for about 90% of the proxies.

```
if(pingResponse.RoundtripTime == 0)
{
    pingResponse = pingTest.Send(proxyNoPort[proxyCount], proxyTimeOut);
    pingResponseTime = pingResponse.RoundtripTime;
}
```

Comment: Do you ever assign to `proxyTimeOut`? Your code shows it as unassigned, which means .NET will initialize it to zero (`0`) which means you're sending a ping with a zero-second timeout.

Comment: Also, `Ping` implements `IDisposable` so you should wrap it in a `using()` block. Also consider using the `SendAsync` `Task` API method instead of the blocking `Send` method so that your program can better-handle different error conditions and not block the UI thread.

Comment: That is an extremely keen eye on you. I'll try that now :)

I forgot I assign timeout in a different class haha so thats not the issue.

Comment: Dai unfortunately using "using" hasn't worked. It still gives me the same "0" response for some proxies, although it has made it check the list faster so thats good news ^.^

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that using code from this forum isn't always the best and you should maybe look into the official documents. It turns out when the pings response is "0" that means it has failed to connect.

I fixed my code completely by replacing

```
if (pingResponse != null && pingResponse.RoundtripTime < proxyTimeOut)
{
    pingResponseTime = pingResponse.RoundtripTime;
    return true;
}
```

with

```
if (pingResponse.Status == IPStatus.Success && pingResponse.RoundtripTime < proxyTimeOut)
{
    pingResponseTime = pingResponse.RoundtripTime;
    return true;
}
```

Although not all is bad as the use "Dai" informed me I should be using the "Using" tags and that has sped up my proxy checking significantly, thanks!